# Is it possible to have gestures with trackpads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, touch, gesture

On a Macbook Pro in Chrome, sliding two fingers across the screen allows you to move backwards and forwards. How do I go about disabling this, and creating custom gestures in jQuery or Javascript?

All I really need to know is how do you detect when two fingers are on the trackpad, which I assume is the best way to do this. You can do it on mobile with e.touches!

Comment: what operating system do you want to target?

Comment: any which supports interaction really.

Comment: This would be really awesome, but first we need to get support on the OS level. If you're interested, vote for Precision TouchPad API on Windows Feedback: https://aka.ms/Uun1l5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Touchpads do not trigger touch-related events (but usually control the mouse pointer instead. This cannot be affected by a website for obvious reasons) so that's not possible.

If gestures done on a touchpad have non-standard behaviour this is usually done by the touchpad's driver/software.

Answer (score 10):

**Update May 2017**

- Chrome has implemented the new [wheel-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent). Pinch-Zoom can be detected as a wheel-event with `ctrlKey === true`.
- Firefox is [going to ship](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1052253) the same behaviour in Fx55.
- Edge supports the wheel-event [unless you are using a "precision-touchpad"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7134034/). No Idea what about pinch-zoom.
- opera probably matches chrome-behaviour (not tested)
- safari has basic wheel-events and supports the proprietary (yet kinda great) [gestureEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GestureEvent)

**Original Answer**

As of April 2016, the pinch-zoom gesture is supported in (very) different ways in different browsers:

- Chrome sends `mousewheel`-events with `ev.ctrlKey===true`
- Mozilla is discussing matching chrome-behaviour: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1052253
- In modern Safari (>9.1) gesture-events can be used: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/gestureevent
- Edge is unlikely to handle it at all.

Comment: It's true that pinch-zoom on the trackpad triggers `wheel` events with `event.ctrlKey === true`, but `event.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to do anything, the browser still zooms the page. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Since a while, browsers will treat certain-events as passive by default to make scrolling smoother, so you have to pass `{passive:false}` as third argument to your event-listener (read: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/scrolling-intervention). Maybe that helps?