# mousewheel,wheel and DOMMouseScroll in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

`DOMMouseScroll` only works for Firefox.

`wheel` seems to work for both Firefox and chrome. What is this? Haven't found docs on this one.

`mousewheel` doesn't work for Firefox.

How should I use them, in order to gain best browser-compatibility.

Example given:

```
document.addEventListener('ScrollEvent', function(e){
   DoSomething();
});
```

Comment: `"scroll"` as the event works for me on Chrome & Firefox, are you looking to particularly target the mouse wheel and ignore scrolling via the scrollbar?

Comment: `wheel` "should" work. im atm looking into it why its not working ;_;

Comment: [The `wheel` event on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) => [Cross-browser implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ecP6R/2/ `wheel` works, only `e.deltaY` is different in browsers, so speed differs. (warning: trippy!)

Comment: As of today, I see `mousewheel` working for both Firefox and Chrome and `wheel` working only for Firefox

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would suggest that all three of them be used at the same time to cover all browsers.

**Notes:**

1. In versions of Firefox where both the **`wheel`** and **`DOMMouseScroll`** events are supported, we need a way to instruct the browser to execute only **`wheel`** and not both. Something like the following:**`if ("onwheel" in window) ...`**
2. The above check though, in the case of **`IE9`** and **`IE10`** will fail, because even though these browsers support the **`wheel`** event, they don't have the **`onwheel`** attribute in DOM elements. To counter that we can use a flag as shown later on.
3. I believe the number returned by **`e.deltaY`**, **`e.wheelDelta`** and **`e.detail`** is not useful other than helping us determine the direction of the scroll, so in the solution below **`-1`** and **`1`** will be returned.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* The flag that determines whether the wheel event is supported. */
var supportsWheel = false;

/* The function that will run when the events are triggered. */
function DoSomething (e) {
  /* Check whether the wheel event is supported. */
  if (e.type == "wheel") supportsWheel = true;
  else if (supportsWheel) return;

  /* Determine the direction of the scroll (< 0 → up, > 0 → down). */
  var delta = ((e.deltaY || -e.wheelDelta || e.detail) >> 10) || 1;

  /* ... */
  console.log(delta);
}

/* Add the event listeners for each event. */
document.addEventListener('wheel', DoSomething);
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', DoSomething);
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', DoSomething);
```

---

*Although almost 3 years have passed since the posting of the question, I believe people who stumble upon it in the future will benefit from this answer, so feel free to suggest/make improvements to it.*

Comment: To be more verbose, when you use the wheel event listener, both firefox and chrome will fire off of this event, but one results in a WheelEvent, and the other results in a DOMMouseScroll being passed to the callback. The DoSomething function is called twice here. it is called once for the wheel listener and once for the other browser-specific listener. the check at the top uses a global variable to track, but this isn't the best way to actually do something, as you will only do something once.

Comment: In the current case, using a global variable is the best way, because **we need to check once**. It's not like a browser will suddenly start supporting the `wheel` event between different event calls @avatarofhope2.

Comment: I'm not sure what `else if (supportsWheel) return;` is for. The way it's written, that will never return. What are those two lines supposed to do?

Comment: If the `wheel` event is supported, we don't want the other two events to run the event handler again, so we use the flag to stop the function early. If the `wheel` event isn't supported, the flag will never be set to `true`, so the other events will run the handler, each in their respective browsers @PhilTune.

Comment: This doesnt support veritical scrolling, some mice have that, using a combo of deltaX and deltaY should give you up down left and right

Answer (score 3):

In case your goal would be prevent scrolling up and down, but browser gives you error due to DOM level is passive, just pass **{passive: false} as the third argument** within .addEventListener method:

```
// Solution to this: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312
window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {e.preventDefault()}, {passive: false}); // no more mouse wheel scrolling [both sides]
// window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {e.preventDefault()}, {passive: true}); this is default behaviour
```

Answer (score 1):

You can feature detect wheel support like this:

```
var wheelEvt = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : //     Modern browsers support "wheel"
          document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : // Webkit and IE support at least "mousewheel"
          "DOMMouseScroll"; // let's assume that remaining browsers are older Firefox
```

then you can attach your event handler like so:

```
$("#wrapper").on(wheelEvt, function(e) {
console.log(e.deltaY);
if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    $("#Left").click();
} else if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
    $("#Right").click();
}
});
```

or if using vanilla js:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener(wheelEvt, function(e) {
console.log(e.deltaY);
if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    $("#Left").click();
} else if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
    $("#Right").click();
}
}, false);
```

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Comment: This **doesn't work** for IE9 and IE10, which, despite supporting the **`wheel`** event, don't have the **`onwheel`** attribute on DOM elements.

Comment: I don't have IE9 or IE10 to test now, but I left a reference from MDN stating that it does have onwheel.
Here is another less authoritative resource:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp
Can you please provide evidence it doesn't work?

Comment: Check out the note under **Browser Support** in the resource you linked to above. Also, you can find a report about the issue in IE9 and IE10 [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/782835/missing-onwheel-attribute-for-the-wheel-event-although-its-supported-via-addeventlistener). Anyway, the issue is here: `"onwheel" in document.createElement("div")`, because the **`onwheel`** attribute is not supported on DOM elements in these browsers. Hope it helps ☺️