# Style input type number more plus button on the side

Tags: html, css

there is any way to style input type number like this?

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Yes ! There are ways to design like this. You have to try first and if stuck then ask specific problem. Not the whole design !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing Increment Arrows on Input of Type Number Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below you can see the snippet and if you wanna see it in JSFIDDLE, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/74xa8Ler/

To explain a bit, how the whole thing works: Here, you'll use `css` for some styling *manipulation*.

But in the `html` code, you see 2 buttons:

```
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]')" ></button>
```

One with `.stepDown()` and the other one with `.stepUp()`. As you can see `querySelector` is being used to *connect* these buttons to your `input`.

So the way it works when a `button` is clicked, it looks at your `querySelector` and after that, the **action** which is `.stepUp()` or `.stepDown()` and apply it to your `input`.

Remember if you have several inputs with `type="number"`, you can't simply do `.querySelector('input[type=number]')"` on all of them. You would need to add `id` or `class` to each `input` or even `input[name=yourName]` and let the `querySelector` *select* your correct `input`.

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #474747;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.number-input button:before,
.number-input button:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #212121;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.number-input button.plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color:#9be3df;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-input">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
  <input class="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain which parts are relevant and why

Comment: Thank Rubioli, it is easier than I think :D