# Override html input[type=number] styling for changing the arrows

Tags: html, css

I have to build a custom arrow button for the `HTML` `input[ type=number]` I tried a couple of examples from the internet couldn't archive what I want.i to want to implement something like below.i not very good with `css`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i think this code is exact match with your requirement
```

`Link Here`: https://jsfiddle.net/mohitraiyani/mje4zco5/2/

`javascript` , `html`, `css`