# How do I take a user's input and store it to be used in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

Absolute beginner and trying to create a very simple decimal to binary converter. I know there exist easier/cleaner ways built into Javascript for converting to different number bases, but I liked creating my own script from scratch. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>GetBit</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Decimal to Binary</h1>
    <p><input type="number" min="0" id="decimal"</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="getBit()">Submit</button>
    <p>here is your answer:</p><p id="binary"></p>


<script>
function getBit() {
  var n = document.getElementById("decimal").value;
  if (n >= 2) {
    bit = (n % 2) + "" + bit;
    return getBit(n = Math.floor(n/2), bit)
  } else {
    bit = 1 + "" + bit;
    return bit
  }
  var bit = document.getElementById("binary").innerHTML;
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure this is atrocious code, but I am doing trial by fire. Really, on the whole, I would like to understand better how user input and Javascript functions interact, and the best practice for placing user input into variables and then using those value to output a new value (like taking a decimal number and outputting binary).

I had tested my getBit() function in the console, and it returned the correct binary. I changed it slightly for my HTML. Here's the original JS that worked:

```
function getBit(n, bit = "") {
  if (n >= 2) {
    bit = (n % 2) + "" + bit;
    return getBit(n = Math.floor(n/2), bit)
  } else {
    bit = 1 + "" + bit;
    return bit
  }
}
```

I'm stumped on how this should be translated into a  element in HTML. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also note that your first input is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your expression around:

```
document.getElementById("binary").innerHTML = bit
```

Your original expression would have assigned the current HTML-content of the chosen DOM element into your variable `bit`.

```js
document.querySelector('#decimal').addEventListener('input',function(ev){
   document.getElementById("binary").innerHTML=getBit(ev.target.value)});
   
function getBit(n, bit="") {
  if (n >= 2) {
    bit = (n % 2) + "" + bit;
    return getBit(n = Math.floor(n/2), bit)
  } else {
    bit = +n + "" + bit;
    return bit
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Decimal to Binary</h1>
<p><input type="number" min="0" id="decimal" placeholder="enter a decimal number">
<p>in binary this is:</p>
<p id="binary"></p>
```

I changed my event listener to look for `input` events now and also the statement in your `else` condition to `bit = +n + "" + bit;` as otherwise the decimal `0` would have been "converted" to `1`.

Comment: Fwiw, `keyup` doesn't work with a 'number' input (number scroll-wheel), the value has to be typed-in.

Comment: Interesting to hear. These input types seem to be handled differently depending on browser and OS used. It works fine in my (old) Android phone.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396364/2610061 ?

Comment: And maybe the `input` event works for your number scroll-wheel too now? I just changed my post.

Comment: That works for me now. Checked Chrome and FFox. (Btw, 3 missing semicolons at the ends of statements).

Comment: Interesting point about the semicolons! Maybe have a look at this:  https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/

Comment: I thought I read about that somewhere, maybe the rules on JSLint. Feels weird but there you go.