# How can I add (+/-) Button Number Incrementers to this Code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I hope y'all are good!

Can you help me to make this quantity picker from Dropdown to be like this one with - and + buttons:

[image: Example]

I want to do this feature on this code:

```
<div style="" class="fields">
 <div class="options">
  <span class="text">Quantity</span><p>:</P>
   <select id="quantityF" name="entry" placeholder="Quantity" required>
     <option style="font-size:12px" value="1" selected disabled hidden>1</option>            
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you so much guys in advance for your help!

Comment: So do you want a dropdown or an input field?

Comment: @kmoser I want quantity picker like the one in the image I've attached with question above, if you have example about input field to see if it can do the job I want or no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for an `<input type="number">`, not a `<select>`. There's [a w3schools example here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number).

It's possible to style the increment/decrement buttons. I suggest referring to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css)