# How to create these buttons in html with bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

[image]

Please, guys, help me out with "how to create such buttons in my navigation bar."

Comment: Did you draw these inputs yourself as an example, or did you see them somewhere?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov no, I didn't draw, i saw them in a screenshot that is assigned to me to implement with the help of HTML and Bootstrap.

Comment: When selecting, should the icons inside the input change?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov no that notification is fixed, that won't change, however, a list of notification will be displayed after clicking the arrow signs

Comment: Look at these solutions. The second solution will work for you, but you just need to customize it a little. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css#