# How to display number input's arrows in both desktop and mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

now I'm developing web-service that has number-type inputs. Instead of standart "typing" input I want to disable it and allow only to input with these "arrows" as you can see down here. There wouldn't be problem if this arrows would appearing in mobile device screen, but their not :(

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
&darr; This is an input with disabled typing
<br>
<br>
<input min="0" max="10" type="number" onKeyDown="return false">
&larr; How to show this arrows also on mobile???
```

Did anyone have ideas how to display this arrows in mobile screen?

Comment: You can check [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396280/customizing-increment-arrows-on-input-of-type-number-using-css).

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "Spinbox" input. It's not (yet) supported by default on mobile browsers. You can have a look at jQueryMobile. It includes Spinbox UI controls

Comment: I would recommend creating your own UI and display for arrow only input.