# Is it possible to track events on clicking on the number buttons on a readonly input?

Tags: javascript

A readonly number input (`<input type="number" readonly/>`) can't be changed when a user clicks on the little up&down buttons. However, is there an event or some other trick to listen to events in JS when the user clicks on these buttons?

I understand it's possible to manually create these buttons as standalone elements near the input, but the input will lose its "number" powers

Comment: you mean click event for `up&down` button?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi that's right

Comment: Ok you have button to set `readonly` prop to true and false and you want to attach click listener to the button? what is problem?

Comment: If the input is `readonly`... Why would you want to know if the users clicks on the buttons to change the value?

Comment: Keeping it number would be the easiest way to keep the number validation and have the buttons that increment and decrement a value. I thought if there was a way to track the clicks on these up&down buttons, it would be possible to change the readonly input.

Comment: You don't need to use input, just use `div, span p or..`

Comment: in this case, I would need to implement increment and decrement logic by myself. As I see it's the only option so I'm developing it. The original idea was impossible

Answer (score 0):

The field It still listens to clicks - Chrome does not show the buttons when readonly

Why do you even keep it number? If it is readonly?

```js
document.querySelector("[type=number][readonly]").addEventListener("click",() => console.log("clicked the readonly"))
```

```html
<input type="number" readonly/>
```

Discussion here

[Detecting number input spinner click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072192/detecting-number-input-spinner-click)

Comment: Keeping it number would be the easiest way to keep the number validation and have the buttons that increment and decrement a value. But it seems, it's not possible. Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to validate a readonly number?

Comment: Why would you need to detect a click on a readonly number?

Comment: Why not just use a span?

Comment: Because the increment and decrement buttons are out of the box in the number field. My task is to make a readonly field that can be changed using the buttons. As I see the only option is to make the buttons by myself. The original idea is impossible

Comment: True. Make your own on a text field