# Detect when HTML number input stepper arrows clicked

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, dom-events

Is it possible to detect when the stepper arrows are clicked in an HTML number input? My inputs are arbitrary size decimals, so I have an attribute `step=0.00000001` to have a valid `<input type=number>`. However, the stepper arrows should increase/decrease by `0.01`. So if a function can be called when those arrows are clicked, I can programmatically increase/decrease the input.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least for now. However, you can manage this using the `input` event. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49567045/3689977).

Comment: Thank you for that link @Alexis88. I don't think that specific answer is relevant, but the next answer could be. If I could compare the previous value and the value right after a mouseclick, then I would know if a stepper arrow was clicked as opposed to a manual entry.

Comment: Oh, I got it. In that case, you can use a `data-attribute` or a global variable. Basically you need to set an initial value and when the `input` event occurs, just compare the new input value to the stored one.

Comment: @Alexis88 does the `input` event occur immediately after a mouse click? If a person manually sets the value to whatever the stepper arrow would normally set it to, then I want to leave it. Otherwise, if it was the stepper arrow, I want to increase the step by a lot.

Comment: It does. The `input` event fires when an `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>` value has been changed. When you click on the `<input type="number">` arrows, you automatically change the element's value. That's why the `input` event fires just after that. Here's more information about [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the onChange function:

```
<input type="number" step="0.00000001" onChange="alert('change')" />
```

**Edit:**

I think for your specific example you would need to use a combination of onChange, onmousedown and onkeydown.

Your input html would look like:

```
<input id="in" type="number" step="0.00000001" onmousedown="downValue(this.value)" onkeydown="resetValue()" onChange="changeValue(this.value)" />
```

And you would need to use some javascript to store and check the change of the values like so:

```
var storedValue = "";

function downValue(e) {
    storedValue = e;
}

function changeValue(e) {
  if (storedValue !== "" && storedValue !== e) {
     console.log("Do Something");
  }
}

function resetValue() {
  storedValue = "";
}
```

Comment: How does that tell me when the stepper arrows were clicked? The `change` event also occurs if the user types in a new value. Is there a way to distinguish between the two? Maybe the `event` object passed to the listening function tells us?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to avoid manual input. If so you can add `onkeydown="return false"` aswell to avoid manual input. Or you could replace 'return false' to detect manual input. It's somewhat the opposite of what you're after but could be used in the same sense. Theres also onmousedown but it would also detect any click unfortunately.

Comment: I want both manual input and stepper arrow functionality, but if the stepper arrows are clicked, I want the step size to be much bigger than what the `step` attribute dictates.

Comment: I've edited my answer as I think it may solve your issue using a combination of onChange, onmousedown and onkeydown

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean like this?**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="my-number"]');
const result = document.querySelector(".result");

inputElement.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  result.textContent = `Your number ${event.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="my-number">

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: No. I wouldn't be able to differentiate between manually setting the number versus clicking on the stepper arrows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As a complement for my comments:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("[type=number]");
let temp = input.value;
      
input.addEventListener("input", _ => {
    if (input.value > temp){
        console.log("The new value is greater than the old one");   
    }
    else if (input.value < temp){
        console.log("The new value is lesser than the old one");
    }
    else{
        console.log("The value stays the same");
    }
    
    temp = input.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```