# Which events should I listen for to hide a custom context menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, contextmenu, dom-events, popupmenu

I wonder which events I should listen for to hide my custom context menu, a `<div>` element shown from an `oncontextmenu` event handler, just like in the native one.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple actions that close the native context menu:

- **Click outside:** Listen for a [`document.onmousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) and, in order to prevent clicks on other (valid) elements from bubbling up and closing the context menu, you would stop its propagation in the intermediate handler with [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

  [`document.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) would also work, but the context menu will remain visible until you release the mouse button instead of disappearing just when you press it.

  In touch devices, you should listen for [`document.touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart), as some devices like iPads don't fire `click` events.
- **Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>:** Listen for [`document.onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) and check if the pressed key is <kbd>Esc</kbd> checking [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), [`KeyboardEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) and [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).
- **Change tab/window**: Listen for [`window.onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur).
- **Mouse scroll:** In Chrome, listen for [`document.onmousewheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel). Take a look here for a detailed answer on how to detect the mouse wheel on different browsers: [mousewheel,wheel and DOMMouseScroll in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204282/mousewheel-wheel-and-dommousescroll-in-javascript).

  The native context menu closes when this happens, no matter if the page has a scroll or not, at least in Chrome on Windows 10.

Here's a simple example with some of the options I mentioned:

```js
const contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');
const MARGIN = 10;

document.oncontextmenu = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const target = e.target;

  if (contextMenu === target || contextMenu.contains(target)) {
    // A right-click on the context menu itself (or anything inside it) will NOT reposition it:
    return;
  }
  
  contextMenu.style.left = `${ Math.min(window.innerWidth - contextMenu.offsetWidth - MARGIN, Math.max(MARGIN, e.clientX)) }px`;
  contextMenu.style.top = `${ Math.min(window.innerHeight - contextMenu.offsetHeight - MARGIN, Math.max(MARGIN, e.clientY)) }px`;

  contextMenu.classList.remove('hidden');
};

contextMenu.onmousedown = (e) => {
  // We don't want this click to close the context menu, so we stop its propagation:
  e.stopPropagation();
};

// EVENTS THAT CLOSE THE CONTEXT MENU:

window.onblur = () => {
  contextMenu.classList.add('hidden');
};

document.onmousedown = () => {
  contextMenu.classList.add('hidden');
};

document.onmousewheel = () => {
  contextMenu.classList.add('hidden');
};

document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Escape' || e.which === 27 || e.keyCode === 27) {
    contextMenu.classList.add('hidden');
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#contextMenu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  transition: box-shadow ease-in 50ms;
}

#contextMenu:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

#contextMenu:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

#contextMenuImage {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="contextMenu" class="hidden">
  <img id="contextMenuImage" src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/3o7aTskHEUdgCQAXde/giphy.gif" />
</div>

RIGHT-CLICK TO SEE THE CONTEXT MENU
```

Note that there's also a check inside the `oncontextmenu` handler to prevent a  right-click on the context menu itself from repositioning it.

Comment: Very useful, thanx. Got my vote. But should the keyCode for escape not be 27 instead of 70?

Comment: @BrunoEberhard Yes, you are right, just fixed it  Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Use the `oncontextmenu` event.

```
el.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // here what you wanna show for example the customised context menu 
    // myContextMenu();
    return false;
}, false);
```

Don't forget to return false, otherwise the standard context menu will still pop up.

Comment: you don't need the return false, just the preventDefault

Comment: @mooga thanks but how this solution can treat the menu like native one(such as if you click on somewhere on the page, the menu can hide)