# Is there a way to prevent scrolling but get the direction and value of the scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touch, scrollbar

Is there any way we can prevent scrolling but also get the direction and the distance scrolled?

I'm aware that we can do that with the `mousewheel` event but I want it to work also in the case of scrolling with the scrollbar (and if it's possible with the touch event). Also I do **not** want to put `overflow: hidden` in `body`.

*I'm pretty sure that it might not be possible at all. Thanks for any input.*

So let's say we have this and we want to change the slides based on the scroll direction and the distance scrolled but without actually scrolling:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollEvent, {
        passive: false
    });

    function scrollEvent(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.wheelDelta) {
            // up
        } else {
            // down
        }

        // I need to know the value of the scroll and for all scroll events
        // also for the scrollbar event and if possible the touch event for mobile
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  
}

.another_component {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.tha-component {
  
}

.tha-component > * {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #323232;
  border-radius: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.tha-component > .active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="another_component">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur id ligula in sem maximus dapibus id ullamcorper libero. Nulla bibendum magna ut ligula bibendum, eu ornare quam malesuada. Vivamus congue, tortor eu euismod finibus, massa ante finibus urna, at maximus erat tellus quis nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum bibendum congue neque, non vehicula orci. Maecenas eget sollicitudin tortor. Vestibulum ut luctus est. Phasellus nec consequat turpis, vel lobortis tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur tempor viverra lacus et tempus. Nam quis mi eu eros convallis placerat.
        </div>

        <div class="tha-component">
            <div class="active">Slide 1</div>
            <div>Slide 2</div>
            <div>Slide 3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="another_component">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur id ligula in sem maximus dapibus id ullamcorper libero. Nulla bibendum magna ut ligula bibendum, eu ornare quam malesuada. Vivamus congue, tortor eu euismod finibus, massa ante finibus urna, at maximus erat tellus quis nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum bibendum congue neque, non vehicula orci. Maecenas eget sollicitudin tortor. Vestibulum ut luctus est. Phasellus nec consequat turpis, vel lobortis tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur tempor viverra lacus et tempus. Nam quis mi eu eros convallis placerat.
        </div>
        
        <div class="another_component">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur id ligula in sem maximus dapibus id ullamcorper libero. Nulla bibendum magna ut ligula bibendum, eu ornare quam malesuada. Vivamus congue, tortor eu euismod finibus, massa ante finibus urna, at maximus erat tellus quis nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum bibendum congue neque, non vehicula orci. Maecenas eget sollicitudin tortor. Vestibulum ut luctus est. Phasellus nec consequat turpis, vel lobortis tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur tempor viverra lacus et tempus. Nam quis mi eu eros convallis placerat.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try the `onscroll` event listener. From what I understand, you want to create an 'automatic slideshow' that varies based on the scroll. You can detect each scroll change using the event listener, and change/update whatever you need to through getting the `body`'s scroll and some conditional javascript.

Comment: But how will I be able to prevent the scroll in this case?

Comment: You can use $event.preventDefault()$ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: But if then if I preventDefault I will not be able to have the direction nor the changed scroll value. And as I mention in the post, I don't want it only for the wheel scroll, but arrows, directional scroll, scrollbar scroll as well as wheel scroll.

Comment: One way that I can think of is to put a transparent div on top of it, detect scrolling from that, and adjust the 'bottom layer' accordingly. You can also imitate a scrollbar on the side, and detect scrolling from that.

Comment: You can also look at `e.deltaY`, `e.wheelDelta`, and `e.detail` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204282/mousewheel-wheel-and-dommousescroll-in-javascript/43837834