# How do I disable the browser back button in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried it in the `.run` method:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {              
  if (!defaultValue.isAuthenticated)
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

but it did not work

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript This could help you.

Comment: You should not disable the users standard navigation features

Comment: also you can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182993/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-going-back-forward-in-history-when-scrolling-horiz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)